# "This is a good day" vs "It is a good day" vs "Today is a good day" vs "It is a good day today"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, usage, american-english, spoken-english

Are these sentences below interchangeable?

> 1. This is a good day.
> 2. It is a good day.
> 3. Today is a good day.
> 4. It is a good day today.

As far as I can remember all of them can be used.

If we can use them all interchangeably, can I also replace **"day"** with **"week"**, **"month"** and **"year"** in all those sentences? Like *"This is a good year."*, *"It is a good year."*. *"This year is a good year."*, *"It is a good year this year."* etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they're all pretty much interchangeable.  However, depending on the context, all of these are for things like the weather, or current events, something that's not likely to change.  Otherwise it's more common to use the future tense (if projecting ahead to the rest of the day) or the perfect tense (if looking back at the day so far).

> It's **going to be** a good day.
>
> **It's been** a good day

This is why it would be unusual to extend these for longer periods while still keeping the present tense, because you really don't know what the future might hold.  Instead, again, use the future or present perfect:

> This **is going to be** a good year.
>
> This **has been** a good year.

Comment: Thank you. I can use "important" instead of "good" in those sentences I gave, right? Like *"This is an important year."*, *"It is an important year."*, *"It is an important day."* etc.

Comment: @FireandIce  Yes, that's fine.  The *importance* of the time period doesn't vary the same way its *goodness* might ... although in some cases it may sound better to use the future or the perfect tense.